# Requiring single negated query not working

Tags: solr, negation

I have a system at my hand that generates solr queries.
`-(+(id:34))` returns everything that does not have id 34, which is correct
`+(-(+(id:34)))` does not return any result, but as of my understanding should return exactly the same result

solr queries are generated. i tried the two queries mentioned above manually. one works, one does not

as soon as one or more "not"-queries `-(...)` are required by a `+(...)` and there is NO OTHER type of subquery required the result set is empty

Comment: Initial guess; this is because for pure negative queries (i.e. when you query `-foo:bar`, the total set of documents is implicitly appended before the negative query, so in effect the query is `*:* -foo:bar`. In your case that won't happen, so you end up with a query that has nothing to subtract it result set from, leaving you with an empty result set. `+(*:* -(+(id:34)))` might work. I'm not sure how useful that syntax will be, however.

Comment: yes this works. i have already fixed it this way but due to the architecture of our software the resulting queries that are generated look pretty ugly